# Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the for loop

Tags: java

So I'm supposed to make a deck of cards and I'm doing it in this way.  No CT error but I get IndexOutOfBound Exception.  I dont know why.
The class Card is already defined.  The value goes up to 12 and the suit goes up to 3, inclusive. Thank you!

```
ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card> (52);

public StandardDeck()
{
   buildDeck();
}

public void buildDeck()
{
   int index = 0;
   for(int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++)
   {
      for(int value = 0; value <= 12; value++)
      {
         deck.set(index, new Card(value, suit)); 
         index++;
      }   
   }

}//buildDeck
```

Comment: What does `ArrayList#set(int, Object)` do?

Comment: it sets an object to the index specified by int!

Comment: In my case, I'm traversing the arraylist and adding a Card object to it. 13 of each suit

Comment: @PTheCoolGuy the answer is in your above statement "adding". See below answer.

Comment: Your misunderstanding stems from the init of the ArrayList. 52 just says that initial allocation of the internally used array provides 52 places, but the *list* is still empty.

Comment: @laune yes I mistook capacity for size.  my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
for(int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++)
{
   for(int value = 0; value <= 12; value++)
   {
      deck.add(new Card(value, suit)); 
      index++;
   }   
}
```

The arraylist doesn't have anything in it yet you need to add first then you can use set for valid indexes.  Once you have the full deck then you can do `deck.set(index, card);`.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please say why if you are going to downvote.

Comment: i cant vote at all because it says i need 15 reps which i dont have yet

Comment: @PTheCoolGuy ya I know it wasn't you I was just wondering who did and why.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use

```
deck.set(index, new Card(value, suit));
```

Use

```
deck.add(new Card(value, suit));
```

[set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())`. Therefore, before you add the i'th element, you can't call `set(i-1,...)`, which is exactly what you tried to do.